# Ionic loading data THEN display home page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my Ionic application, I load all the data (via http requests) at the opening of the app.

I want to make sure that all my http requests are done and THEN display the home page. In the meantime, the idea is to display a loading screen.

What is the best way to do that ?

```
angular.module('App.Common', [])
    .service('myData', function($http, API_URL) {
        this.initData = function() {
            self.getDataType2(); //calls http request
            self.getDataType2(); //calls http request
            self.getDataType3(); //calls http request
            self.getDataType4(); //calls http request
            self.getDataType5(); //calls http request
            self.getDataType6(); //calls http request
        };
});


angular.module('App.Home', [])

.controller('Ctrl', function(myData) {
    myData.initData();
});
```

And in my home.html, while initData() is not done, I display a loading page.

I know that loading part would be with this code

```
  $ionicLoading.show({
    content: 'Loading',
    animation: 'fade-in',
    showBackdrop: true,
    maxWidth: 200,
    showDelay: 0
  });
```

but how/when to use

```
$ionicLoading.hide();
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First you need to make sure all requests are resolved**

In order to accomplish this goal you can use the built in $q service. You'll end up with a service like this:

```
angular.module('App.Common', [])
    .service('myData', function($q, $http, API_URL) {
        this.initData = function() {
            return $q.all([
                self.getDataType1(); //calls http request
                self.getDataType2(); //calls http request
                self.getDataType3(); //calls http request
                self.getDataType4(); //calls http request
                self.getDataType5(); //calls http request
                self.getDataType6(); //calls http request
            ]).then(function(data1, data2, data3, ...) {
                return { data1: data1, ... };
            });                
        };
    });
```

This will give you an `initData` method which returns a promise object when all http requests are done.

**Then in order to prevent a view from being loaded until data is ready you need to configure your state to use resolve data.**

```
angular
    .module('App', ['ionic', 'App.Common'])
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: '/path-to-your-state-view',
                    controller: 'HomeController'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                data: function($ionicLoading, myData) {
                    $ionicLoading.show();

                    return myData.initData().finally($ionicLoading.hide);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

**Finally you have to tell your controller to wait for that resolve dependency to load.**

```
angular
    .module('App')
    .controller('HomeController', function($scope, data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
```

I assumed quite a bit about your app (state, module names, etc) but I hope this serves as a starting point.

All relevant sources are:

[angular $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and [ui-router state resolves](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#inherited-resolved-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Have each function for getting data return the $http call result which will be a promise.  Use $q.all and pass it the array of promises the call to $q.all will return a promise that resolves when all the other async calls resolve.  Use a variable like scope.model.loading or could be a property of the service and set it to true before you call to init and false in the $q.all handler.  Use that variable in the view to decide what to show.

```
angular.module('App.Common', [])
    .service('myData', function($http, API_URL) {
        this.dataLoaded = false;
        this.initData = function() {

            let data2 = self.getDataType2(); //calls http request
            let data3 = self.getDataType2(); //calls http request
            let data4 = self.getDataType3(); //calls http request
            let data5 = self.getDataType4(); //calls http request
            let data6 = self.getDataType5(); //calls http request
            let data7 = self.getDataType6(); //calls http request

            return $q.all([data2,data3,data4,data5,data6,data7]).then(function(){
              self.dataLoaded = true;
            })
        };
});


angular.module('App.Home', [])

.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, myData) {
    myData.initData();
    $scope.myData = myData; // in the view you can just bind to myData.dataLoaded in an ng-if or ng-show to toggle showing/hiding certain parts
});
```

Comment: you mean this way?  let promises = [promiseAlpha(), promiseBeta(), promiseGamma()];

$q.all(promises).then((values) => {
    console.log(values[0]); // value alpha
    console.log(values[1]); // value beta
    console.log(values[2]); // value gamma

    complete();
});

Comment: Yup something along those lines unfortunately the promise doesn't have a pending flag though so you'll have to keep track of the pending/loading state yourself. You may also consider resolves on a state definition since the controller and template are deferred until resolve promises complete but this will stop you from showing the loading screen unless you made that a "intermediary" state... Not typical.

Comment: But then what should I use instead of     myData.initData(); ?

Comment: @Doapper I just posted some example code assuming all those data functions return a promise what I wrote should work, let me know if it's still unclear, also keep in mind this is just A solution there are many ways to skin this cat depending on what exactly you want to have happening.

Comment: Also if you choose to use the ionic service for showing loading instead can just trigger the show loader where we set dataLoaded to false here and make the call to hide it when we set dataLoaded to true... since the initData returns the promise the controller could do that work as well if you choose.